# Permission Denied Error While Saving Excel During Loops

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm working on building a small Google Geocode API app for a project. I read in an excel file of long/lat combos, then loop for a bit calling the geocode api to get a specific value from the returned json, then I save that to an excel file. In order to account for potential failures resulting in loss of my work, I have multiple calls of .save() (from openpyxl) during the loops.

This process works for awhile, ~20-200+ loops, and then I'll get a permission denied error on the file I'm trying to save to.

This doesn't seem to match the other permission denied questions I've seen since I know I have permission since some of the saves work. After a permission denied error I can verify on the Excel that each save prior to the failure was successful.

My suspicion is I don't fully understand how .save() (perhaps it has some limitations in how frequently it can be called?) operates (but didn't see anything from documentation that helped me), and there is probably a better way to handle this process. Thanks for any advice!

Code below:

```
  import urllib
import requests
import json
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook 
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time

main_api = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

api_key = 'plz no steal'

#Load workbook for long/lat
workbook_in = load_workbook("crimexlonglat.xlsx")
rowNum = 625
loopCnt = 1

# #Declare workbook
wb = load_workbook("testxl.xlsx")
#wb = Workbook()
#grab active worksheet. Not sure why this is necessary
ws = wb.active

while (rowNum < 1000):
   print('Loop ' + str(loopCnt))
   #check for invalid lat/long and skip
   if workbook_in['Sheet1']['A'+str(rowNum)].value == '0.00000000,0.00000000' or workbook_in['Sheet1']['A'+str(rowNum)].value == '-1.00000000,-1.00000000':
       ws['A'+str(rowNum)] = ''
       rowNum = rowNum + 1
       loopCnt = loopCnt + 1
       wb.save("testxl.xlsx")
   else:
        address = workbook_in['Sheet1']['A'+str(rowNum)].value
        url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address': address, 'key': api_key})
        json_data = requests.get(url).json()
        #Dump and load seems unncessary. Need to understand this better.
        outputJson = json.dumps(json_data) 
        parsedJson = json.loads(outputJson)
        ws['A'+str(rowNum)] = parsedJson['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name']
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
        loopCnt = loopCnt + 1
        wb.save("testxl.xlsx")
   time.sleep(1)

wb.save("testxl.xlsx")
```

Error text:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\johnsonm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\johnsonm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\johnsonm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\johnsonm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\johnsonm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\johnsonm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\johnsonm\OneDrive - XXX\Documents\Python Learning\API Projects\Test.py", line 44, in <module>
    wb.save("testxl.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\johnsonm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 409, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\johnsonm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 292, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\johnsonm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'testxl.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a minimal example first to troubleshoot where the problem is.
Try to run this:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time

# #Declare workbook
wb = Workbook()
# grab active worksheet. Not sure why this is necessary
ws = wb.active

for rowNum in range(1000):
    print('Loop ' + str(rowNum))
    ws.append(['Some text', 42])
    wb.save("testxl2.xlsx")
    # time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Everything ran fine with that limited test. Ran your original version, then ran it again with change of "Workbook()" to "load_workbook("testxl2.xlsx")" just to see if that changed the outcome, but worked just fine.

My assumption with .save() is that the entire save process has to finish before the program moves forward, is it possible however that the save could still be going on when it hits the next loop and then it fails?

Comment: Could a solution be to NOT save it in each loop? Just once at the end?

Comment: That was my original code (not shown here), however once I lost a few thousand rows due to some bad data I didn't anticipate further down the line I decided to throw in those extra saves.

Comment: Thanks the help. I split the difference and have the saves happen only ever 100 loops. 4000 successful writes and counting.